# Trailhead challenge

Tags: salesforce1-app, trailhead

I am working one the Module Build Reusable Lightning Components in the Unit Create an Indicator Badge Apex Service, I did all the steps but when I tried to verify this step I get an error:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:  There was an
>   unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check
>   from completing: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Since it is only two Copy / Paste the chanllange of this unit, can someone help me with this ?

Comment: There is one thing you can try. Set debug log in your org and than click on finish challenge button in trailhead. Then when error come check logs generated. You might see at which part error is coming, then please edit your question and add those details.

Comment: Go back and reread through the directions. There's a good chance you forgot to install a package/manual record creation. I've done that a few times. I've also spun up the wrong type of dev org for a few of them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Click the App Launcher icon and select ZBSLightning.
Click Load Data and then Initialize Sample Data to import the data.Then check the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misprint in the task:

URL Mapping there is: `/Accounts/*/contacts` not `/Account/*/contacts`

Comment: I'm not sure if this really is an answer to the question (which is itself a tad vague). Can you expand on your answer to make it more clear what you're talking about? Best practice for answers is to include all of the relevant details so that people don't need to leave your answer (like clicking links would do).

Comment: There is a misprint in the task: they asked in task create REST service with url mapping: '/Account/*/contacts' 

But when they validate your code they put URL  '/Accounts/*/contacts'. 

To see this you can add debug message in your getAccount() method:

System.debug('URL: ' + RestContext.request.requestURI);

Answer (score 0):

Create an Contact record with the FirstName as Gerta

```
[SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'Gerta' LIMIT 1]
```

Former Query is creating the problem.

Comment: Please do not ask for best answer on Salesforce Stack Exchange. The asker and the community will provide that feedback where appropriate.